# Get largest values from multiple columns from latest timestamps in MySql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a list of the`*usedpc` values across multiple similar columns, and `order desc` to get worst offenders. Also, I need to only select the values from the most recent timestamp for each `sys_id`.
Example data:

```
Sys_id | timestamp | disk0_usedpc | disk1_usedpc | disk2_usedpc
---
1  | 2016-05-06 15:24:10 | 75 | 45 | 35
1  | 2016-04-06 15:24:10 | 70 | 40 | 30
2  | 2016-05-06 15:24:10 | 23 | 28 | 32
3  | 2016-05-06 15:24:10 | 50 | 51 | 55
```

Desired result (assuming `limit 2` for example):

```
1 | 2016-05-06 15:24:10 | disk0_usedpc | 75
3 | 2016-05-06 15:24:10 | disk2_usedpc | 55
```

I know I can get the max from each column using `greatest`, `max` and group timestamp to get only the latest values, but I can't figure out how to get the whole ordered list (not just max/greatest from each column, but the "5 highest values across all 3 disk columns").

EDIT: I set up a SQLFiddle page: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82202/1/0

EDIT2: I'm very sorry about the delay. I was able to get all three solutions to work, thank you. If @PetSerAl can put his solution in an answer, I'll mark it as accepted, as this solution allowed me to very smoothly customise further.

Comment: Like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82202/16)?

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to achieve, thank you. If you put the query as an answer I'm happy to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `vm_disk` table with three row table to create separate row for each of yours disks. Then, as you have row per disk now, you can easily filter or sort them.

```
select
  `sys_id`,
  `timestamp`,
  concat('disk', `disk`, '_usedpc') as `name`,
  case `disk`
    when 0 then `disk0_usedpc`
    when 1 then `disk1_usedpc`
    when 2 then `disk2_usedpc`
  end as `usedpc`
from
  `vm_disk` join
  (
    select 0 as `disk`
    union all
    select 1
    union all
    select 2
  ) as `t`
where
  (`sys_id`, `timestamp`) in (
    select
      `sys_id`,
      max(`timestamp`)
    from `vm_disk`
    group by `sys_id`
  )
order by `usedpc` desc
limit 5
```

Comment: This was the answer that retrieved the desired result first for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this would work... I know it may look pretty redundant but it could save overhead caused by doing multiple joins to the same table:

```
SELECT md.Sys_id,
md.timestamp,
CASE
  WHEN
    md.disk0_usedpc > md.disk1_usedpc
      AND
    md.disk0_usedpc > md.disk2_usedpc
  THEN 'disk0_usedpc'
  WHEN
    md.disk1_usedpc > md.disk0_usedpc
      AND
    md.disk1_usedpc > md.disk2_usedpc
  THEN 'disk1_usedpc'
  ELSE 'disk2_usedpc'
END AS pcname,
CASE
  WHEN
    md.disk0_usedpc > md.disk1_usedpc
      AND
    md.disk0_usedpc > md.disk2_usedpc
  THEN md.disk0_usedpc
  WHEN
    md.disk1_usedpc > md.disk0_usedpc
      AND
    md.disk1_usedpc > md.disk2_usedpc
  THEN md.disk1_usedpc
  ELSE md.disk2_usedpc
END AS pcusage
FROM mydatabase md
GROUP BY md.Sys_id HAVING MAX(md.timestamp)
ORDER BY pcusage DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select
    t1.sys_id, t1.`timestamp`,
    case locate(greatest(disk0_usedpc ,disk1_usedpc ,disk2_usedpc), concat_ws(',' ,disk0_usedpc ,disk1_usedpc ,disk2_usedpc))
        when 1 then 'disk0_usedpc'
        when 1 + length(concat(disk0_usedpc, ',')) then 'disk1_usedpc'
        when 1 + length(concat(disk0_usedpc, ',', disk1_usedpc, ',')) then 'disk2_usedpc'
    end as usedpc,
    greatest(disk0_usedpc ,disk1_usedpc ,disk2_usedpc) as amount
from yourtable t1
join (
    select max(`timestamp`) as `timestamp`, sys_id
    from yourtable 
    group by sys_id
) t2 on t1.sys_id = t2.sys_id and t1.`timestamp` = t2.`timestamp`
order by t1.`timestamp` desc
-- limit 2
```

[<kbd>SQLFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5e256/10)

How it works, the sub query here is try to get the latest row for each group `sys_id`, as one kind of way in many solutions. Then you should get the greatest column in `disk0_usedpc ,disk1_usedpc ,disk2_usedpc`, as you wrote in your question, the function `greatest` is the plan. So `greatest(disk0_usedpc ,disk1_usedpc ,disk2_usedpc) as amount` can help you get the amount.

But also you want that column's name, here I used `locate` and `concat`, `concat_ws`(which avoids writing so many separators, here is comma `,`).

Let's take row

#### `1  | 2016-05-06 15:24:10 | 75 | 45 | 35`

as an example:

`concat_ws(',' ,disk0_usedpc ,disk1_usedpc ,disk2_usedpc)` will give us "***75,45,35***", here 75's index in this string is 1, 45 is 4, 35 is 7.
As you see, `locate(greatest(disk0_usedpc ,disk1_usedpc ,disk2_usedpc), concat_ws(',' ,disk0_usedpc ,disk1_usedpc ,disk2_usedpc))` will return 1, so the greatest row is `disk0_usedpc`, here it makes.